Subfolder(s) of IMAPFolder not showing
I am trying to access a subfolder of a shared inbox, but my code shows there are no subfolders (even though there are several)
My code is the following:
Application outlookApp = new Application();

// Log in to Outlook
NameSpace outlookNamespace = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");

string recipientName = "SharedInbox";
Recipient recip = outlookNamespace.CreateRecipient(recipientName);
recip.Resolve();

if (recip.Resolved)
{                

    // Inbox
    MAPIFolder inboxFolder = outlookNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

    Debug.WriteLine(inboxFolder.FullFolderPath);
    foreach (MAPIFolder folder in inboxFolder.Folders)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(folder.FullFolderPath); // Never reached
    }

    // Processed
    //inboxFolder.Folders.Add("Processed"); // Little test I did, it shows up in outlook!
    Debug.WriteLine("added:");
    foreach (MAPIFolder folder in inboxFolder.Folders)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(folder.FullFolderPath); // even though I just added a subfolder and it shows up in Outlook, still never reached!
    }

    rappyAssistFolder = inboxFolder.Folders.Cast<MAPIFolder>().Where(r => r.Name == "Processed").FirstOrDefault();

I've tried all different forms of iterating over the folders and subfolders, but it seems like there are none.

If you open a shared folder and the parent mailbox is not added wholesale as one of the delegate mailboxes, Outlook only caches in the primary OST file the folder itself, but not its subfolders.
Try to either

Make sure the mailbox in question is added to Outlook and the whole mailbox is visible in the Outlook folder treeview.
Turn cached mode completely
Turn caching mode off for the delegate mailboxes.


It was already visible in Outlook. Turning off caching did indeed work. Thanks!

Little update: If I turn cache back on, it still works (even after reboots).
